# htaccess block direct access to specific file extensions with exceptions

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to prevent users from accessing any files or directory directly except from my index.php using this htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?REMOVEDLINK [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?REMOVEDLINK.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|js|css)$ - [F]
ErrorDocument 403 http://REMOVEDLINK/404.html
ErrorDocument 404 http://REMOVEDLINK/404.html
```

I just used another htaccess within my php includes folder:

```
deny from all
```

Everything works fine except for the fact that it prevents my favicon from being displayed. Code from my index.php:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
```

How can I allow access for the favicon to be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just below `RewriteEngine On` line include this rule to allow access to `favicon`:

```
RewriteRule img/favicon\.png$ - [NC,L]
```